# How does a Plasmodium move?

Tags: biochemistry, movement

*Plasmodium* sp. does not have any locomotory organs. So, how does it move? What biochemical process allows it to move?

Answer (score 3):

#### Short answer: Only some stages of plasmodium are motile.  These use "gliding motility".

Gliding motility relies on actin filaments, which enable the organism to deform it's shape, facilitating movement.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lENfxodf6RQ) provides a good visual representation of the filament-based motility.

> "Gametocytes develop into gametes in the insect midgut, and then fertilize each other to form motile zygotes, which escape the gut."

[image: An ookinete (motile), a sporozoite (motile) and a merozoite (non-motile) of Plasmodium falciparum.]

The ookinete and sporozoite are motile.  The merozoite is non-motile.

Then of course there is the circulatory system of the host.

**Source:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmodium
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867400812817

Comment: You did not answer the OP's question.

Comment: What makes the sporozoite and ookinete motile? Are there any filaments responsible for cell movement?